# how to implement log4net in c# and what is need of log4net?

Tags: log4net

i just want to know that, what is use of log4net in application and how i`m gonna implement in c#.

i am done with some of the research that i am put under it.

```
public static class Logger
{
    private static log4net.ILog Log { get; set; }

    static Logger()
    {
        Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Logger));
    }

    public static void Error(object msg)
    {
        Log.Error(msg);
    }

    public static void Error(object msg, Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(msg, ex);
    }

    public static void Error(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
    }

    public static void Info(object msg)
    {
        Log.Info(msg);
    }
}
```

}

above is just a method that maintain log in separate file i just want to know in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.First you have to add a reference for **log4net.dll** if you havn't done that yet.

2.Then you have to add that statement above your stating class declaration. You can put it right bellow your using statements and outside of your class declaration:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

3.The class that you already have created.

4.Add that config to your configSections tag on your web.config/app.config:

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
```

That will allow you to add tags to configure your log.

5.Add that to your configuration tag on your web.config/app.config:

```
<log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="./Log/log.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <datePattern value="'.'yyyy_MM_dd" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="30" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date{yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss,fff} %-5level %logger [%thread] %message %exception%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

6.Then you just have to call the methods on your Logger class.

If you want more information i'll sugest you to read the blog of that guy [Log4Net Tutorials and Resources](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorials-and-Resources.aspx)